# CountDigits(long), not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

**(I am aware that this has been asked already, but I don't quite understand the answers I've seen)**
I have to receive a number, and give back the amount of the digits who makes it up, as a function.

as a example, i receive the number **250** and i print back **3**

there is only one error who stops me from debugging.
"not all code paths return a value"

here is the code! (The error is in the 2ND line, bolded)

```
class Program
{
    **public static long CountDigits(long n)**
    {
        if (n >= 0)
        {
            if (n < 10)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 1 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 2 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 3 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 10000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 4 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 5 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 6 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 10000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 7 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 8 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 9 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 10000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 10 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 11 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 12 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 10000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 13 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 14 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 15 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 10000000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 16 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 100000000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 117 Digit(s)");
            else
            if (n < 1000000000000000000)
                Console.WriteLine("you have 18 Digit(s)");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("error! Re-check Please!");

        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NO TIME TO EXPLAIN ENTER NUMBER!");
        long  n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(CountDigits(n));

    }
```

Comment: `-1000` has 4 digits but will be considered as having 1 digit in your code

Comment: Okay, Problem is solved now! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining the type of your function as `long`, it's expected that the evaluation of the method upon execution is a value of `long`. However, in your method, you don't return any values, but rather, you execute a WriteLine method to print out to your console directly.

What you should be doing instead is return the length (of it as a string) of the passed long value `n`, or like snr suggested, a divisional iteration.

Then when you have the evaluated value, you print it like you wanted to print it originally.

```
class Program
{
    public static long CountDigits(long n) {
        return Math.Abs(n).ToString().Length;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("NO TIME TO EXPLAIN ENTER NUMBER!");
        
        long  n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("You have " + CountDigits(n) + " digits!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `long CountDigits(...)` you specify a return value of type long. However, you never return anything, instead you are using `Console.WriteLine` to immediately print the result.

### Simplest/quickest solution

Make that method a `void CountDigits(...)`. And then also remove the Console.WriteLine from around the call to this method - you are never returning anything, so there is nothing to print.

### Intermediate solution:

Change the return type to `string`. Instead of

```
        if (n < 10)
            Console.WriteLine("you have 1 Digit(s)");
```

Use

```
        if (n < 10)
            return "you have 1 Digit(s)";
```

and keep that `Console.WriteLine(CountDigits(n));` in your Main.

### Longer solution, but IMO better:

Keep the return type (or use an `int` return type - you don't need the range of `long`) and replace all `Console.WriteLine`s with a `return` specifying the length.

So instead of

```
        if (n < 10)
            Console.WriteLine("you have 1 Digit(s)");
```

use

```
        if (n < 10)
            return 1;
```

And in your Main, replace `Console.WriteLine(CountDigits(n));` with

```
Console.WriteLine("You have " + CountDigits(n) + " digit(s)");
```

One issue that you have now: you will have to deal with the "unsupported length" scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a return value. So, you should alter `long` with `void`

Further, you can even use the following code snippet helping to prevent line pseudo-line duplication and to use for non-positive numbers as well.

```
int count = 0;
while (n > 0)
{
   n = n / 10;
   count++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"you have {count} Digit" + count <= 1 ? "" : "s");
```

Comment: Can you specify a line for this? i Don't understand the context of alter

Comment: try to study. No ready answer improves your learning curve.

Comment: @VDM alter means to change. Change `long` to `void` on the method `CountDigits`. Also you should learn how return types work before working with it. I think you meant to replace `Console.WriteLine` with `return {long}` and print it to console in Main with `Console.WriteLine(CountDigits(x));`

Comment: @DudeManGuy as i change the "long" to "void, i get another error-
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: change `Console.WriteLine(...)` to `CountDigits(n);`